# Sort Array in c#, even numbers in descending and odd numbers in ascending without using predefined sort function

Tags: c#, sorting

I want to sort the given array using C#, like even numbers in descending and odd numbers in ascending without using the build in sort functionality. I want the array to be sorted in the same given array, first even numbers then the odd numbers.

Example: given array is

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

then I want this to be sorted like

```
arr = {8,6,4,2,1,3,5,7};
```

I tried the below code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        SortArray(arr);
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void SortArray(int[] arr)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j<arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j])
                {
                    if (arr[j] % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        temp = arr[i];
                        arr[i] = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

Output: 4 2 3 1
Expected Output: 4 2 1 3
```

Comment: Given the order for two or more odd numbers and the order for two or more even numbers, what orders should have odd respect to even numbers? should they be interleaved? or should be all odd numbers before all even numbers? or the opposite? or should they land into two different new arrays?

Comment: In the same array, first even numbers in descending order and then the odd numbers in ascending order. Example, if the given array is {1,2,3,4} then expected output us {4,2,1,3}.

Comment: @Kumar BTW, the limited sample data and Output in your question is a misleading. If you expand your sample data to have an array of 8 elements going from 1 to 8, then you will see that your code's output will actually be "8,3,1,5,2,6,7,4". Always try to use a good amount of sample data, especially when testing loops and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matter is what comparison to perform. Any sorting algorithm is suitable, as long as it uses the correct comparison criteria.

Current comparison criteria are:

1. Even numbers before odd numbers
2. Greater even numbers before smaller ones
3. Smaller odd numbers before greater ones

Choose your favorite sorting algorithm and invoke a comparer that apply those criteria.

Main comparison, just a `Comparer` for ease of use, but you can extract the `Compare` method, make it static, and use it alone:

```
public class EvenOddComparer : Comparer<int>
{
    public override int Compare(int value1, int value2)
    {
        // returns -1 if value1 must be placed before value2
        // returns +1 if value1 must be placed after value2
        // returns 0 if value1 equals value2

        var even1 = value1 % 2 == 0;
        var even2 = value2 % 2 == 0;
        // first is even and second is odd
        if (even1 && !even2)
            return -1;
        // first is odd and second is even
        if (!even1 && even2)
            return +1;

        // both are even
        if (even1)
            return -value1.CompareTo(value2); // descending
        // both are odd
        else
            return value1.CompareTo(value2); // ascending
    }
}
```

Sorting method, that receives the array of values and a reference to the comparer. You can remove the `comparer` parameter and invoke the comparison method of your choice directly instead of `comparer.Compare`. Here we have a Bubble sort, just for simplicity:

```
public static void Sort(int[] values, Comparer<int> comparer)
{
    for (int ixItem1 = 0; ixItem1 < values.Length - 1; ixItem1++)
        for (int ixItem2 = ixItem1 + 1; ixItem2 < values.Length; ixItem2++)
        {
            var item1 = values[ixItem1];
            var item2 = values[ixItem2];

            var needSwap = comparer.Compare(item1, item2) > 0;
            if (needSwap)
            {
                values[ixItem1] = item2;
                values[ixItem2] = item1;
            }
        }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
var values = new[] { 8, 3, 1, 5, 2, 6, 7, 4 };
Sort(values, new EvenOddComparer());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any sortalgorithm you want, but you just need to adapt the comparison function a little bit to respect your requirements. I'll do an example for a bubble sort like algorithm

```cs
void sortArray(int[] a) {
  for (int j = a.Length; j > 0; j--) {
    for (int i = 0; i < j - 1; i++) {
      if (greaterThan(a[i], a[i+1])) {
        var tmp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = tmp;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The comparison function `greaterThan(a,b)` returns `true` if `a` should be considered greater then `b` and takes into account all your requirements for the sorting:

- even numbers before odd numbers. So if one is even and the other is odd, `greaterThan` returns true, only if the second is even, ie "smaller".
- even numbers descending. So if both numbers are even, `greaterThan` returns true if the first one is less then the second one (to reverse order)
- odd numbers ascending. So if both numbers are odd, `greaterThan` return true if the first one is greater then the second one (to preserve order)

```
bool greaterThan(int a, int b) {
  bool aeven = a % 2 == 0;
  bool beven = b % 2 == 0;
  
  if (aeven ^ beven)  //one is even the other is odd
    return beven;

  //here both are even or both are odd
  //so if a is even, so is b, if a is odd, so is b
  return aeven 
    ? a < b //sort even numbers descending, thus invert comparision
    : a > b; //sort odd numbers ascending
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As OP asked for an answer "*without using the build in sort functionality*", try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class MainClass {
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        SortArray(arr);
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void SortArray(int[] arr)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        List<int> listEVENs = new List<int>();
        List<int> listODDs = new List<int>();

        // split array into EVEN and ODD numbers, using LIST because it is easier
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length ; i++)
        {
          if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
          {
              listEVENs.Add(arr[i]);
          } else {
              listODDs.Add(arr[i]);
          }
        }

        // convert the EVEN and ODD lists back to arrays
        int[] arrEVENs = listEVENs.ToArray();
        int[] arrODDs = listODDs.ToArray();

        // Manually sort (descending) even number array without using built-in functions
        for(int i=0; i<arrEVENs.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1; j<arrEVENs.Length; j++)
                {
                    
                    if(arrEVENs[j] > arrEVENs[i])
                    {
                        temp = arrEVENs[i];
                        arrEVENs[i] = arrEVENs[j];
                        arrEVENs[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }        

        // Manually sort (ascending) ODD number array without using built-in functions
        for(int i=0; i<arrODDs.Length; i++)
            {
                for(int j=i+1; j<arrODDs.Length; j++)
                {
                    if(arrODDs[j] < arrODDs[i])
                    {
                        temp = arrODDs[i];
                        arrODDs[i] = arrODDs[j];
                        arrODDs[j] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }        

        // concatenate the EVEN and ODD number arrays
        Array.Resize(ref arr, (arrEVENs.Length + arrODDs.Length));
        arrEVENs.CopyTo(arr, 0);
        arrODDs.CopyTo(arr, arrEVENs.Length);

        
    }
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
8
6
4
2
1
3
5
7
```

Comment: If OP also does not want to use Lists, then dynamic arrays can be used with the resizing code blocks added, but the general logic can stay the same.  i.e. split original array into EVEN and ODD numbers, sort each as you like, then concatenate in the order desired. There is also scope to break down the SortArray() function into 2 or 3 sub-functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer.

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        SortArray(arr);
        foreach (int i in arr)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void SortArray(int[] arr)
    {
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] < arr[j])
                {
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.Length; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i] % 2 != 0)
                {
                    temp = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
8
6
4
2
1
3
5
7
```

Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score -1):

```cs
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var sortedArray = arr.Where(item => item % 2 == 0).OrderByDescending(item => item).Union(arr.Where(item => item % 2 != 0).OrderBy(item => item));            
foreach (int i in sortedArray) {
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Where:

- `arr.Where(item => item % 2 == 0)` gets the even values
- `.OrderByDescending(item => item)` order them descending
- `arr.Where(item => item % 2 != 0)` gets the odd values
- `.OrderBy(item => item)` order them ascending
- `Union` joins the 2 lists together

Comment: I doubt the usage of LINQ is something useful for someone who is learning coding

Comment: I doubt using LINQ passes the requirement of *not using predefined sort function*

Comment: I'm not an expert in LINQ, I know only the basics. But, still after seeing your code it encourages me to learn more about LINQ. I never thought this can be done with few lines of code. Thanks for your work and to everyone.

Comment: @derpirscher my bad, did not see this in the title

Comment: @MaxXapi My profile could say I'm the pope, wouldn't make it true. No professional is going to be askign about a basic high school/uni coding assignment, that's for sure.